# Is there a function in python that takes in the OS name as input and outputs the distribution it is based on?

Tags: python

For example if I input-"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" I should get that it is based on Fedora 19. Is there a library which could do that for me in Windows.

Comment: Windows doesn't have distributions.  What information are you hoping to get?  There is no "general purpose" solution to this, because "distributions" are strictly a Linux concept.  Remember RedHat is a distribution, Fedora is a distribution, Ubuntu is a distribution, Debian is a distribution.  Linux is the operating system.  The question has no meaning.

Comment: Sorry, but that answers caters to the OS currently in the system. I want to just input any os name and get the distribution not just the system I am running it on.